# Linux CSV Remove Duplicate based on old date

Tags: linux

We have the Following CSV file which contain

DCR_Path,Direction for Translation,Date & Time

```
data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:22

data2,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 02:21

data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:23

data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2013 03:24

data3,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:10

data2,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 02:22

data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 02:20
```

I need to take the latest and remove the other duplicates and output should be:

```
DCR_Path,Direction for Translation,Date & Time

data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:23

data2,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 02:22

data3,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:10
```

I tried Below command but it is not deleting the data based on old date.

```
sort -u -t, -k1,2 filename.txt
```

Any help to delete the Duplicate data based on old date and keep only latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace  _YOUR_FILE_...

```
awk -F ',' '{ if (Z) { "(date --date=\""$3"\" +\"%s\")" | getline X ; if (Y[$1] < X) { Y[$1] = X; C[$1] = $0 } } else { Z = $0 } } END { print Z ; for (V in C) { print C[V] } }' < _YOUR_FILE_
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer it is working fine for small files and for the Big file I am getting  awk: (FILENAME=merged-2014-11-12.csv FNR=145116) fatal: cannot open pipe `(date --date="Nov 6 2014 02:53 " +"%s")' (Too many open files) Any help on resolving the above Issue.. Thanks.

Comment: please clarify what is big files: "many files in directory (how many?)" or "one big file (how many lines in a file? run: wc -l < BIG_FILE )"

Comment: Think perl script can do what you want. 100%